# How to get integer of an index of an array in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's suppose we have an array:

```
array = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

and I want to get the Index by knowing a value (a):

```
array.firstIndex(of: "a")
```

this then gives me 'Optional(1)', but how can I get an Integer from that?

Comment: It's an optional. So unwrap it. e.g. `if let index = array.firstIndex(of: "a") { ... }`. Or use `guard let` syntax. You'll really want to invest a little time getting up to speed on optionals in Swift as they're an essential part of the language. See [Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330) discussion in _The Swift Programming Language._

Answer (score 4):

```
guard let index = array.firstIndex(of: "a") else { return }
print(index)
```

or

```
if let index = array.firstIndex(of: "a") {
    print(index)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`firstIndex()` returns a value of type `Int?`, so like any other optional type you will have to unwrap it somehow.

The developer docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) list a few different ways to do just that. Without knowing exactly how you want to use this value, it's hard to know which method will be best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to unwrap the Optional value, or you can use a `?` to use optional chaining to reference the integer iff it's non-nil:

```
guard let index = array.index(of: "a") else {
    ...
}
...
```

OR

```
let index = array.index(of: "a")
index?.description
```

Comment: `if let` is also another great solution if you have a section of code you only want to have ran if the value exists.  I personally prefer using `guard` since it's more explicit in its intention